Binding TextBox to String Varriable
I am really struggling with getting a TextBox to bind to a string variable and have tried various solutions on the interweb with no success. Perhaps someone can point out what I am doing wrong?
Xaml
 <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SteelBlue}" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.8">
     <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TCGTextBox}" Text="{Binding ProgramManager.ProgramName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  GotFocus="TCG_TB_Focused" CornerRadius="0" LostFocus="TCG_TB_UnFocused" x:Name="TCG_TestProgramName" ></TextBox>
</Border>

ProgramManager is declared in my MainWindow.xaml.cs file thusly
TestPrograms ProgramManager = new TestPrograms();

C#
public class TestPrograms : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{



    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }



    public int Selected_Test = 0;

    private string _ProgramName = string.Empty;

    public string ProgramName
    {

        get => _ProgramName;

        set
        {
            _ProgramName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }


    }


    public void LoadTestProgram(TestProgramsViewModel program)
    {

        ProgramName = program.Test_Name;

    }
}

Whenever I call LoadTestProgram(), _ProgramName is updated correctly, but the UI is not updating. I have tried doing this with static variables and using x:Bind, but still can't get it to work. Appreciate and help with this.

Have you set the DataContext of your View to the correct ViewModel?

Can you provide an example? I'm still learning this so I'm not sure I know what you mean.

I got it!  Thank you. I managed to see what was missing thanks to this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/992567/how-to-set-bindingcontext-in-winui3

Feel free to post your answer here and mark it as accepted for others who might needed it as a reference.

I am glad you were able to get it working. A small side note have a look at Community Toolkit MVVM it is a library that provides a lot of classes and support for MVVM-related stuff you will have to manually implement. It is a great source when working with MVVM. There git repository also has great samples.

So, as mentioned by 0x436f above, I hadn't set the datacontext. To do this I edited the following in my XAML.
<Border x:Name="ROOTPANEL" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SteelBlue}" BorderThickness="1" Opacity="0.8">
     <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TCGTextBox}" Text="{Binding ProgramManager.ProgramName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"  GotFocus="TCG_TB_Focused" CornerRadius="0" LostFocus="TCG_TB_UnFocused" x:Name="TCG_TestProgramName" ></TextBox>
</Border>

Adding a name to the border element and calling it ROOTPANEL in this case.
Then I set the datacontext of ROOTPANEL to the correct ViewModel.
TCGRootPanel.DataContext = ProgramManager;

Note, ROOTPANEL can be higher up the treeview so as to capture more child elements if they are all accessing the same VM.
